# Проблема с заменой картинки в ImageView в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, imageview

Проблема заключается в следующем: при нажатии на ImageButton должна заменится картинка в `ImageView`

Код написан вроде верно, но при запуске приложения оно останавливается сразу же, после нажатия на эту `ImageButton`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема.

Мой java код:

```
package com.example.killerlii.nedaibogzafeilit;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.FocusFinder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nazvanie);
        Typeface meCustomFont1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LegionaryBold.otf");
        t.setTypeface(meCustomFont1);

        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.predpisanie);
        Typeface meCustomFont2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LegionaryItalic.otf");
        t.setTypeface(meCustomFont2);

        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opisan);
        Typeface meCustomFont3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Legionary.otf");
        t.setTypeface(meCustomFont3);


        RelativeLayout mainpage = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainpage);
        ScrollView Opisanie = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Opisanie);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        final TextView nazvanie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nazvanie);
        final TextView predpisanie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.predpisanie);
        final TextView opisan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opisan);
        ScrollView Perecheslenie = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Perecheslenie);
        final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        final ImageButton imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        final ImageButton imageButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        final ImageButton imageButton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        final ImageButton imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        final ImageButton imageButton6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
        final ImageButton imageButton7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        final ImageButton imageButton8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
        final ImageButton imageButton9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);
        final ImageButton imageButton10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);




        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer ring= MediaPlayer.create(main.this,R.raw.firsts);
                ring.start();

                nazvanie.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.imageButton1));
                predpisanie.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.imageButton1_1));
                opisan.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.imageButton1_2));
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_2);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Кстати, советую не называть `view` так одинаково и давать им почти одинаковые бессмысленные id. Это ваш код! А самому себе делаете неудобно вот и путаетесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде объявляется переменная `ImageView image`, но не инициализируется :)

Добавьте строку

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageId);
```

Comment: Цены вам нет,спасибо большое)

Хотелось бы ещё задать вопрос,но каплю не по этой теме
Как сделать на этой-же кнопке остановку песни,при повторном её нажатии?
Если и тут поможете,то  буду очень признателен

Comment: Вообще для этого принято создавать новые вопросы, это совершенно другая проблема по другой тематике, задайте другой новый вопрос, я с радостью отвечу :)

Comment: Отметьте ответ как верный, поставив галочку слева от него.